# NVIDIA X Server Settings - PRIME Profiles without Intel Power Saving option available

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, power-management, battery

I have recently received an nvidia update on my Ubuntu 21.10 OS and I am now using nvidia-470, which does not let me use the intel graphics card. I used it for my daily laptop use, because it improved my battery life, and used to change to NVIDIA (Performance Mode) when I wanted to play a videogame.
Now I am worried that my battery life will worsen. Are there any tips for me to improve my battery life given my laptop will always be using the "NVIDIA (Performance Mode)" profile or is there something I can do in order to be able to change it to the Power Saving profile?

Thanks.

Screenshot:
[image: 1]

`dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii`
[image: 2]

Comment: Can't you set this up in the **Nvidia X Server Settings** app?

Comment: The whole problem is that I can't. Otherwise, it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Edit your question and show me a screenshot of the **Nvidia X Server Settings** PRIME Profiles tab, and the **Additional Drivers** window. Also show me `dkms status` and `dpkg -l *nvidia*`. Which Nvidia card do you have?

Comment: I tried to attach a screenshot in the first place, but it wasn't allowed. I'll see if I can do it now.

Comment: You should be running Nvidia 510.54. Choose it in **Additional Drivers**.

Comment: I really shouldn't because I did that and my system wouldn't boot. I had to uninstall the nvidia drivers altogether in order to boot my OS and then reinstall them with the recommended driver, which is 470.

Comment: Please show me the additional info that I requested.

Comment: I have added the requested information to my post.

Comment: I also need the **Additional Drivers** window, and is your Nvidia card the MX130?

Comment: Are you running Wayland or X11/xorg?

Comment: Additional Drivers window is up. X11/xorg

Comment: It's funny, `dkms status` didn't show any kernel drivers. Does `nvidia-smi` show you a display?

Comment: It does, I will also share that.

Comment: Do you have CUDA installed?

Comment: Are you able to select Nvidia on-demand?

Comment: I have just installed CUDA. And I am able to select that profile, yes.

Comment: Is the Intel video enabled in your BIOS?

Comment: What version CUDA did you install?

Comment: CUDA Version: 11.4

Comment: Hum, then I don't know what's wrong with your config. Sorry.

Comment: I'm checking my BIOS.

Comment: I've had CUDA mess with Nvidia display drivers and X server. Unless you actually need it, you should try disabling it.

Comment: @qwr You have to make sure  to install the correct version of CUDA (shown in `nvidia-smi`).

Comment: Ok, I think I have installed CUDA 11.3 and `nvidia-smi` shows 11.4

Comment: @A.J. CUDA  11.3 would be wrong. You have to match `nvidia-smi`.

Comment: @A.J. Do `dpkg -l *cuda*` and see if it shows you the installed version. There's a CUDA CLI command to show you, but I don't know what that is.

Comment: I have removed all nvidia drivers and cuda, installed cuda's latest version and now they all have the same version. It automatically installed the newest nvidia drivers, 510, without any problems so far. Regarding the NVIDIA Settings, now the PRIME profiles tab has disappeared altogether. Is that normal?

Comment: @A.J. Did you already reboot? Show me `dkms status` again.

Comment: It shows: `nvidia, 510.39.01, 5.13.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed`

Comment: @A.J. Also show me `dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii`. This is slightly modified from the earlier dpkg command.

Comment: @A.J. That looks normal now. We didn't get that before with 470.

Comment: @A.J. Reboot and revisit Nvidia PRIME profiles tab.

Comment: @heynnema I have updated the images above.

Comment: @A.J. Did you reboot yet, and check PRIME Profiles? In terminal type `prime-select`, then `prime-select query`.

Comment: @heynnema I have done that. `prime-select` shows `Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|on-demand|query` and `prime-select query` shows `on-demand`. I am guessing I can change it here, but how?

Comment: @A.J. `prime-select intel` or maybe `sudo prime-select intel`.

Comment: And it will save that info when I boot?

Comment: Don't know. You'll have to try it.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: @A.J. You're very welcome!

Comment: @A.J. Funny enough, I just updated my Nvidia driver, and I also lost the Intel Power Saving option! So it's a Nvidia problem.